# Generate deletion, insertion, substitution, transpotions for a string

Tags: java, algorithm

I am implementing a spell checker algorithm. I have constructed a `Trie` that stores my words for quick searching.

When a given input string is passed what I want to do is generate potential deletions, insertions, substitutions and transpositions for that string with an edit distance of 1. Using this super set I can then try to find the word in my `Trie` and offer the user "did you mean?" type results.

I have looked online and most solutions mention calculating the Levenstein Distance. That only works if you already know the two strings and you want to find the edit distance between the two.

Suggestions?

Comment: 1) You can traverse by trie-tree and calcute levenstein distance (use some cut heuristics)

Comment: hmmm not a bad suggestion...can you add more please?

Comment: So, levenstein algorithm we can describe as recursive function D(i,j) that accepts (m,n) where m - length of first string, n - length of second string. Let fix  first string and think about it as input string. So, calculating of d("input","ab") calls d("input","a"). Calculating of d("input","ac") calls d("input","a"). See? You calculate ldistance for current node, traverse to childs and calculate ldistance for them basing on precalf of current node.

Comment: Now, about cut-heuristics. You don't need words with ldistance >= 7. More: you need only N words to suggest them for user. Use some kind of djkstra algorithm for tree

Comment: so as I am traversing the trie to find the word I am also calculating the levenstein distance? I thought I was supposed to generate all deletions, insertions etc. then test those against the trie.

Comment: No, in this algorithm you must traverse in all directions. Btw, you also can generate all modifications of input word but that is too long

Comment: nsinreal your last comment was what my question suggested doing, generate all modifications of the word and try those against the trie...this will be slow

Comment: yep, you suggested to generate all modifications of word. Generating of all modifications is slow. So better calculate Levenstain distance for all words in trie, because all words have some common prefixes and LD for them can be cached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an 2 pass algo:

Pass 1

look and calculate the distance for all  words starting with the same letter as the word to spell check. This will be fast. you can stop the depth search when the number of chars is greater then spell word length + 2 (then this obiously another word)
Display results of pass1, eg by marking word red underline

Pass 2
look for all words and stop when length + 3 or 4
Update the results found in pass 1

Comment: Can you provide some code please? If I get the string test I want to generate tst tes tast tbst or etst etc. and then test that input against my trie.

Comment: i would not generate tst tes tast, etc. you should iterate the trie and calculate the leving distance from the correct word in the trie, to the word to be spell checked. add a word to your result list only when its distance is 1 or 2. finally sort the result by leving distance, and show the first 5 results.

Comment: When you say "iterate" the trie, assuming input is 'trst' (user made a typo) do I just go as far as the trie is and generate all possible results up until the most accurate character I reached? For example given input 'trst' I will start traversting the trie. I see 't' matches then I move on and see 'r' is missing. Am I supposed to go through the rest of the nodes in the trie and then compare the levenstein distance?

Comment: @dnkoutso yep. You must traverse in all directions, even if they doesn't contains characters (or contains new/another). Your cut-heuristic - levDistance > length(word) + magicConstant

Comment: start with "t" and iterate the sub tree, such that you calc the levin dist for all words starting with t. (when this works you can introduce a stop condirion where it makes no sense to iterate deeper into the trie). somewhere in the trie you find the word "test" which has a dist = 1, add object (test, 1) to your result candidates.

Comment: So if node 't' in the trie has nodes 'a' (word -> 'table') and 'e' (words -> [tea, team]) then I must find these words and do a levenstein comparison against my input string...find the closest and represent that

Comment: @dnkoutso *** Optimal to use not depth-first search, but breadth-first search and take from queue not first element, but minimum element (word, where previous calculated distance is smallest). That will guarantee if you have input word already in trie, you will get him first.

Comment: yes breadth first, but you may start with depth first which is easier to implement. once depth works, you are motivated to do breath first. breath firt will give a faster finding of the correct word. but if you search all words, then it makes no diff if depth or breadth first.

Comment: @AlexWien there is a diffirence. In breadth first with min-queue results already sorted by distance. In depth first - you must additionally sort it. But if we talking about all elements, naive realisation of min-queue will take O(n) to add element, so we got O(n^2) where n - max words in queue (maybe can be linearly comparable with number of all words, if we talking about BFS without cutoff heuristics. And this is overestimation, in reality it must be less). And sorting results after DFS - O(mlogm) with smaller constant, where m - number of results.

Comment: @dnkoutso So if you need only limited number of suggestions - use BFS with minimum queue. If you need all suggestions - use DFS

Comment: nsinreal I will be going with DFS for starters.